# Separate column with conditions Using R

Tags: r, regex, string, dataframe

i have dataset for meals have `visitor`, `meal`, `meal_code`, some meal rows have both meal and meal_code and the meal_code filled from the above row.

The 2nd row contain the issue.

| visitor | meal | meal_code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ahmed | water | w1 |
| ahmed | s1 sandwich | w1 |
| khaled | fish | f1 |
| khaled | 2extra coffee | c2 |

I want move the meal_code from meal if have code and fill right. Note that some meal name have number and all meal_code must have number.

I have tried `sep = "\\\\s(?=.\*\\\\d)` but not work.

Comment: Is `2extra` a meal_code? What characteristics does a `meal_code` have that distinguish it -- always letter-digit?

Comment: 2extra not code it is meal. the meal_code is start with letter then number for some meal like 2extra coffee with milk  have another code like c2.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said the meal codes could be `c2` or `c2.1`, you can try the following `stringr` solution:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>%
  mutate(meal_code = coalesce(str_extract(meal, "[a-z]+[0-9.]+"), meal_code),
         meal = str_squish(str_remove(meal, meal_code)))

# # A tibble: 4 × 3
#   visitor meal          meal_code
#   <chr>   <chr>         <chr>    
# 1 ahmed   water         w1       
# 2 ahmed   sandwich      s1       
# 3 khaled  fish          f1       
# 4 khaled  2extra coffee c2
```

Answer (score 1):

I can provide a `tidyverse` based solution, which assumes you are working with a `tibble` as your dataframe object. It will probably work with `data.frame` objects in base, but for the sake of consistency, just feed it a `tibble` to avoid any downstream errors. You can easily convert whatever dataframe you're working with to a tibble using the `as_tibble()` function within `dplyr` (ex. - `new_data <- old_data %>% as_tibble()`.

Another note before I get to the answer–try to provide some code in your reprex to build the dataframe you'd like us to use when answering the question. It saves people like me a bit of time when answering, and helps you get more answers to your question. Not a huge deal, just worth mentioning. **Anyways, onto your answer:**

### First I'll build the dataframe you referenced:

```
library(tidyverse)

meals <- tibble(visitor = c('ahmed', 'ahmed', 'khaled', 'khaled'),
                meal = c('water', 's1 sandwich', 'fish', '2extra coffee'),
                meal_code = c('w1', 'w1', 'f1', 'c2'))

meals

# A tibble: 4 × 3
  visitor meal          meal_code
  <chr>   <chr>         <chr>    
1 ahmed   water         w1       
2 ahmed   s1 sandwich   w1       
3 khaled  fish          f1       
4 khaled  2extra coffee c2
```

### Identifying the Problem

Based on your question and the comments available, it seems like some entries (such as number 2) have a `meal` that contains the correct `meal_code` entry that need to replace the existing `meal_code`. Based on the information provided, I'll make the following assumptions:

- The `meal_code` that needs to be identified will always come before the `meal` that they accompany
- `meal_code` will always be a single lowercase letter immediately followed by a one digit number
- There will always be a space between the `meal_code` and the `meal` in these erroneous entries
- There will only ever be a single `meal_code` to be extracted in the problematic column

These assumptions will be important in generating the `regex` expression.

### Proposed Solution

You will need to iterate through the `meal` column, scan each value for text that fits the above criteria, and if it exists, replace the existing `meal_code` value with it and also remove it from the `meal` column.

### Solution in code

```
cleaned_meals <- meals %>%
  mutate(meal_code = if_else(str_detect(meal, '^[a-z][0-9] '),
                             str_extract(meal, '^[a-z][0-9] ') %>% str_trim(),
                             meal_code),
         meal = str_remove(meal, '^[a-z][0-9] '))

cleaned_meals

# A tibble: 4 × 3
  visitor meal          meal_code
  <chr>   <chr>         <chr>    
1 ahmed   water         w1       
2 ahmed   sandwich      s1       
3 khaled  fish          f1       
4 khaled  2extra coffee c2
```

### Code Explanation

This code is essentially running the two steps (replacing `meal_code` and cleaning `meal` within `dplyr`'s `mutate` function:

1. The first step `mutate`s the `meal_code` column using an `if_else` statement: if the regex `'^[a-z][0-9] '` is detected in the `meal` column, it extracts the string that met that regex from `meal`, and replaced the existing `meal_code` value with it (after trimming leading and trailing white spaces, more on that below):

   - the regex `'^[a-z][0-9] '` is broken down into the following:

     - `'^'` indicates that the regex that follows should only be found at the beginning of the larger string the regex is being applied to
     - `'[a-z]'` will match any lowercase letter
     - `'[0-9]'` will match any single-digit integer
     - `' '` will match a space
   - If this is met with `str_detect` (returns `TRUE`), then this value is extracted with `str_extract`, leading/trailing white spaces are removed with `str_trim`, and then this value is used to replace `meal_code`.
   - if this regex is **not met**, then `str_detect` returns `FALSE`, which just mutates the original value of `meal_code`.
2. The second step `mutate`s the `meal` column using `str_remove`, which searches for the same regex used above. If it is detected, it gets thrown out, and if not, nothing happens.

Go ahead and try this code on your data to see if it works. If it doesn't, I'd guess one of the assumptions I made previously were violated, which means you might have to adjust your regex. If that does happen, hopefully this gives you the tools to go ahead and modify the regex to fit your use. Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

Using `grepl` and `regexpr/regmatches`.

```
rx <- 's\\d\\s'
transform(dat,
          meal_code=replace(meal_code, grepl(rx, meal, perl=TRUE), 
                            trimws(regmatches(meal, regexpr(rx, meal, perl=TRUE)))),
          meal=gsub(rx, '', meal, perl=TRUE))
#   visitor          meal meal_code
# 1   ahmed         water        w1
# 2   ahmed      sandwich        s1
# 3  khaled          fish        f1
# 4  khaled 2extra coffee        c2
```

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- structure(list(visitor = c("ahmed", "ahmed", "khaled", "khaled"
), meal = c("water", "s1 sandwich", "fish", "2extra coffee"), 
    meal_code = c("w1", "w1", "f1", "c2")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```